# Upgrading to Angular Material 5

Tags: angular-material

I am using a beta 8 of Angular Material in my project. It was never been updated since then. Now that v5 is available, we'd like to do so. What things should I consider while doing so? Any information or pointer to it would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is the following:

1. Since `MaterialModule` has been removed, you have to import the modules required for your application separately to either another module (such as `MyMaterialModule` and making sure that it is after `BrowserModule`), a `const`, or adding the modules individually after `BrowserModule`. For more info, visit the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules).
2. The `md` selectors have been removed and replaced with `mat` (as well as classes). To update, install `material-prefix-updater` from `npm`:

   ```bash
   npm i -g angular-material-prefix-updater
   ```

   After npm has installed it globally, run this command on your app's root directory (where the `-p` parameter is the app's `tsconfig.json`):

   ```bash
   mat-switcher -p src/app/tsconfig.json # Or wherever tsconfig.json is
   ```

   For more info, visit the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material-prefix-updater) or use the `--help` parameter.

   *Note: You no longer need to specify `MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE`.*