# Issue in exporting the Angular material modules after migrating to 5.2.2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting the following error after migrating to Angular material 5.2.2. Prior to that my application was in Angular material 2.0.0-beta.10.

After changing the version in the package.json and running the npm install, I also followed the steps mentioned in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726311/6167659

I notice that all the **Md*** tags are changed to **Mat***, but now I am facing the error as

```html
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/messagebox/messagebox-component.ts (2,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MAT_DIALOG_DATA'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/messagebox/messagebox-component.ts (2,27): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjobstatistics.component.ts (12,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjobstatistics.component.ts (21,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjoblog.component.ts (12,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjoblog.component.ts (21,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjobcontrol.component.ts (12,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/sidemenu/sidemenu.module.ts (7,9): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/applications/deleteApplicationDialog.component.ts (4,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/applications/deleteApplicationDialog.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/applications/createApplicationDialog.component.ts (4,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/applications/createApplicationDialog.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/share/share-dialog.component.ts (4,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/share/share-dialog.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/applications/applicationList.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/reports/select-report-dialog.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/reports/editReportDialog.component.ts (4,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/reports/editReportDialog.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/reports/report.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/reports/report.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/select-dashboard-dialog.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/dashboard-app.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/appsettings/appSettingsDialog.component.ts (3,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/home/homePage.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/home/homePage.component.ts (7,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/editDashboardDialog.component.ts (4,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/editDashboardDialog.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/dashboard.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/dashboard.component.ts (5,21): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogConfig'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/dashboard-page/dashboard.component.ts (6,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/utils/error-handler.ts (6,29): Cannot find module 'stacktrace-js'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (58,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatAutocompleteModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (59,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (60,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonToggleModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (61,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatCardModule'.
 
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (65,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatGridListModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (66,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatIconModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (67,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatInputModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (68,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatListModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (69,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatMenuModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (70,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatProgressBarModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (71,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatProgressSpinnerModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (72,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatRadioModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (73,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatRippleModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (74,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSelectModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (75,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSidenavModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (76,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSliderModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (77,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSlideToggleModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (78,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBarModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (79,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatTabsModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (80,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatToolbarModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (81,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatTooltipModule'.
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module .../node_modules/ngx-perfect-scrollbar/dist/ngx-perfect-scrollbar.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in .../src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in .../src/app/app.module.ts
    at Error (native)
    at syntaxError (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25111:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25123:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24553:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Krishnan\RSI\SourceCode\Bluesky Developement\BlueSky Development\Firebolt.Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
ERROR in .../src/app/Services/ClientAPIService.ts (9,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (59,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (60,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonToggleModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (61,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatCardModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (62,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatCheckboxModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (63,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatChipsModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (64,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (65,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatGridListModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (66,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatIconModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (67,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatInputModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (68,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatListModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (69,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatMenuModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (70,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatProgressBarModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (71,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatProgressSpinnerModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (72,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatRadioModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (73,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatRippleModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (74,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSelectModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (75,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSidenavModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (76,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSliderModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (77,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSlideToggleModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (78,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBarModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (79,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatTabsModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (80,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatToolbarModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.module.ts (81,3): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatTooltipModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/app.component.ts (2,9): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatIconRegistry'.
ERROR in .../src/app/sidemenu/sidemenu.module.ts (7,9): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'.
ERROR in .../src/app/Services/ClientAPIService.ts (9,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'.
ERROR in .../src/app/utils/error-handler.ts (6,29): Cannot find module 'stacktrace-js'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisstatussummary.component.ts (5,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjobcontrol.component.ts (12,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjobstatistics.component.ts (12,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjobstatistics.component.ts (21,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjoblog.component.ts (12,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialog'.
ERROR in .../src/app/pages/bisstatus/bisjoblog.component.ts (21,10): Module '".../node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MatDialogRef'.
```

I tried deleting the entire node_modules folder and rerun the npm install, but still the same issue exists. None of the below imported modules couldn't be exported

```
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  ...
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```

What is the mistake I am doing here, why the latest material modules could be referenced/exported?

Comment: Did you update everything else too? Ie. all angular modules, typescript, @angular/cli?

Comment: yes, entire package.json is updated to latest versions.....   "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",

Comment: K. Weird that there's so many components in the trace. I'd think only modules would show up, as that's where the import statements should mostly be (except MatDialog etc). Are they? Also @angular/material/material boggles me a bit, not sure if that's where it's supposed to be looking for the stuff.

Comment: Oh btw, did you remember to list them in the module decorator's imports also? @module({ imports: [ MatButtonModule, ...] })

Comment: yes, I have added these under  imports: [
    BrowserModule,...] in the @NgModule({ ... in app.module.ts

Comment: Typescript updated also? I've had weird issues with 2.7.x which installing typescript@2.6.2 solved

Comment: no recently I have not updated typescript, let me know which version to be installed for the above mentioned angular versions ( 5.2.0 ) ?

Comment: Current typescript version in my system is "Version 2.3.5", which version to be installed for angular material 5.2.0 to work ?

Comment: Try 2.6.2, that might do it

Comment: remove package-lock.json, node_modules and run npm install again

Comment: @Tomasz Kula, removing package-lock.json, node_modules and running npm install again worked. can you please put this in the answer and I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Krishnan No problem. Glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove package-lock.json, node modules and run npm install again.